# Dart how to parse http Json response like this

Tags: json, flutter, dart, model

quiero preparar una clase que me permita leer esta respuesta desde http, he buscado ejemplos pero no logro encontrar algo que me ayude a orientarme sobre esto, les agradezco musho su respuesta.:

```
{
"c5afca9c-2b3e-44f2-9949-eb041b01a1a3": {
    "model_id": "c5afca9c-2b3e-44f2-9949-eb041b01a1a3",
    "product_id": "2162c720-46f0-11ea-9424-5f8a7104fef3",
    "seller_id": "dad255b0-4132-11ea-af4f-e35b2a7d9852",
    "sale_price": 1350,
    "auction_price": 1000,
    "size": 9,
    "typesize": "Hombre",
    "condition": "nuevo",
    "image": "http://legit.mx/images/Jordan_1_Retro_High_Homage_To_Home_(Non-numbered)/",
    "release_date": "2018-05-19",
    "sku": "11111",
    "retail_price": "111",
    "color": "WHITE/CORE BLACK/RED"
},
"d5521c74-21b2-42ea-9e11-3ed3d4e7b684": {
    "model_id": "d5521c74-21b2-42ea-9e11-3ed3d4e7b684",
    "product_id": "6b41e250-415b-11ea-8945-b3e6241283f2",
    "seller_id": "dad255b0-4132-11ea-af4f-e35b2a7d9852",
    "sale_price": 1834,
    "auction_price": 1300,
    "size": 4.5,
    "typesize": "Niño (GS)",
    "condition": "nuevo",
    "image": "http://legit.mx/images/adidas_Yeezy_Boost_350_V2_Zebra/",
    "release_date": "2017-02-25",
    "sku": "2222",
    "retail_price": "222",
    "color": "WHITE/CORE BLACK/RED"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este caso no es tan simple como un parsing the array de objetos, ya que no es un array, es un diccionario con diccionarios dentro, tienes que obtener primero los keys, para luego en base a eso  sacar el objeto, aquí tienes la solución:

Primero, crea tu clase para mapear los objetos

```dart
class MyData {
  final String key;
  final String modelId;
  final String sellerId;

  MyData({this.key, this.modelId, this.sellerId});

  factory MyData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) => MyData(
      key: map['key'], modelId: map['model_id'], sellerId: map['seller_id']);
}
```

Ahora transforma la data obteniendo los keys.

```dart
  final data = {
    "c5afca9c-2b3e-44f2-9949-eb041b01a1a3": {
      "model_id": "c5afca9c-2b3e-44f2-9949-eb041b01a1a3",
      "product_id": "2162c720-46f0-11ea-9424-5f8a7104fef3",
      "seller_id": "dad255b0-4132-11ea-af4f-e35b2a7d9852",
      "sale_price": 1350,
      "auction_price": 1000,
      "size": 9,
      "typesize": "Hombre",
      "condition": "nuevo",
      "image":
          "http://legit.mx/images/Jordan_1_Retro_High_Homage_To_Home_(Non-numbered)/",
      "release_date": "2018-05-19",
      "sku": "11111",
      "retail_price": "111",
      "color": "WHITE/CORE BLACK/RED"
    },
    "d5521c74-21b2-42ea-9e11-3ed3d4e7b684": {
      "model_id": "d5521c74-21b2-42ea-9e11-3ed3d4e7b684",
      "product_id": "6b41e250-415b-11ea-8945-b3e6241283f2",
      "seller_id": "dad255b0-4132-11ea-af4f-e35b2a7d9852",
      "sale_price": 1834,
      "auction_price": 1300,
      "size": 4.5,
      "typesize": "Niño (GS)",
      "condition": "nuevo",
      "image": "http://legit.mx/images/adidas_Yeezy_Boost_350_V2_Zebra/",
      "release_date": "2017-02-25",
      "sku": "2222",
      "retail_price": "222",
      "color": "WHITE/CORE BLACK/RED"
    }
  };

  final myDataList = data.keys.map((item) {
    final itemMap = data[item];
    itemMap['key'] = item;
    return MyData.fromJson(itemMap);
  }).toList();

  print("List: ${myDataList.length}");
  print("First Item : ${myDataList.first.key},  ${myDataList.first.modelId}");
```

Comment: Falta completar los demás campos pero ya lo tienes practicamente listo

Comment: Excelente, me funcionó de maravilla. Muchísimas gracias, tienes algún canal de you tube o fb???

Comment: Aquí tenemos un canal donde hablamos de FlutteR: https://www.youtube.com/c/TheDartSide  ,   grupo de facebook peru: https://www.facebook.com/groups/flutterperu/  , latam: https://www.facebook.com/groups/flutter.dart.spanish/